# Django NameError: name 'password_reset_done' is not defined

Tags: python, django, nameerror

found some topics like this but they are older or not solved.

Well, I'm following a youtube tutorial and I'm stuck in this part of it, I already know it's due the difference of version, I've gone to the docs and got some answers but still can't solve it by myself.

I'll post what I think it's relevant but if you guys want another part of my code ask and I'll get it.

the error as I said (on Traceback) is: NameError: name 'password_reset_done' is not defined

On the tutorial he didn't done anything on views.py about this, he just added some imports on url.py that was deprecated so I fix that but the errors keeps the same...

My accounts/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
    login,
    logout,
    password_reset,
    PasswordResetDoneView,
    PasswordResetConfirmView,
)


urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.home),
    path('login/', login, {'template_name': 'contas/login.html'}),
    path('logout/', logout, {'template_name': 'contas/logout.html'}),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('perfil/', views.view_perfil, name='view_perfil'),
    path('perfil/edit/', views.edit_perfil, name='edit_perfil'),
    path('trocar-password/', views.trocar_password, name='trocar_password'),
    path('reset-password/', password_reset, name='reset_password'),
    path('reset-password/done/', password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/',
    password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),

]
```

just to add some more code. My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
from contas.forms import (
RegistrationForm,
EditPerfilForm,
)
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm, PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash


def home(request):
    numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
    name = 'Lucas Cyrne'

    args = {'myName': name, 'numbers': numbers}
    return render(request, 'contas/home.html', args)

def register(request):
  if request.method=='POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/contas')
  else:
    form = RegistrationForm()

  args = {'form':form}
  return render(request, 'contas/reg_form.html', args)

def view_perfil(request):
    args = {'user': request.user}
    return render(request, 'contas/perfil.html', args)

def edit_perfil(request):
 if request.method=='POST':
    form = EditPerfilForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/contas/perfil')
 else:
    form = EditPerfilForm(instance=request.user)
    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'contas/edit_perfil.html', args)

def trocar_password(request):
  if request.method=='POST':
    form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
        return redirect('/contas/perfil')
    else:
        return redirect('/contas/trocar_password')
  else:
    form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)

    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'contas/trocar_password.html', args)
```

Comment: have you tried importing `password_reset_done`?

Comment: `password_reset_done` this view does't exist the error is obvious

Comment: it looks like 'password_reset_done' is deprecated, I import 'PasswordResetDoneView' instead.

Comment: the same with 'password_reset_confirm'.

Comment: question solved below thx! (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django looks for everywhere, and doesn't see `password_reset_done`

and above your urls patter, there is this:

> NOTE: these built-in CBV are available forn Django >= 1.11

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
login,
logout,
password_reset, # suggestion: PasswordResetView
PasswordResetDoneView,
PasswordResetConfirmView,
)
```

you view is `PasswordResetDoneView`

instead of:

```
path('reset-password/done/', password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
```

it should be:

```
path('reset-password/done/', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause you didn't call `password_reset_done` view, but using it in urls.

`path('reset-password/done/', password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),`

Look this url, you are trying to use `view` that doesn't exist.

Make your own view inheriting `PasswordResetDoneView` or, just use it without registering url. (You only can call url using `password_reset_done` like this

`reverse('password_reset_done')`

p.s. you have to add `django.contrib.auth.urls` to your `urls.py`. like

`url('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),` ( for django =< 1.11 )

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add app_name is urls.py
2. Add views as viewname.as_view() in urls.py